# How to programmatically create object for new row in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `ObservableCollection<IInterface>` which is binded to DataGrid. 
IInterface is interface.

I want to add new row clearly for user (without add button). I've added `CanUserAddRows="true"` but it works only when dataGrid is binded on `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`.

How can I programmatically create new object for new row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently had the same issue. I've posted a solution in my blog: [Enable inline adding of records for view models with non-default constructors/interfaces](http://www.michaelruck.de/2012/07/wpf-datagrid-enable-inline-adding-of.html)

It basically involves creating a custom ListCollectionView (can be done similarly for the others) and binding the grid to that view. The custom view has a factory method used to create the rows as the default implementation in ListCollectionView doesn't support adding rows for interfaces or classes which do not have a default constructor.

Note that even if you do not use a CollectionView in your MVVM view model, but a regular list or an IBindingList, WPF will create a specific collection view for you. See more details [WPF’s CollectionViewSource](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387)

Comment: Thanks! Will try to add this solution in my code when it will be needed.

Comment: The link is currently dead, making this answer incomplete :/

Comment: [Here is an archived version of the link in this answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20170421034734/http://www.michaelruck.de/2012/07/wpf-datagrid-enable-inline-adding-of.html)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: "programmatically" you can add by just adding/inserting an object into your `ObservableCollection` - but I think you want the automatic-adding feature you describe earlier.

The problem is that, the framework cannot know how to create an instance of your Interface - it only knows how to create types with default-constructors.
So you have to change your ObserveableCollection using a concrete type or you cannot use the automatic feature and have to add the object in code-behind.

Comment: I understand it, but may be DataGrid has some event which raises for creating new element. I know about InitializingNewItem but it invokes after creating new element.

Comment: Honestly: I don't know - but this kind of wiring only results in "spaghetti-code" - a thing I strive to avoid.

Comment: It's only one case. Another case is using classes without default constructor.

Comment: Changed code to right. Now question is obsolete, but still not answered (( I can mark your answers as useful. Thanks.